# Operation not allowed for a result set of ResultSet. TYPE_FORWARD_ONLY

Tags: java, mysql

Estoy creando un formulario de consulta, para que al ingresar un nombre dentro de un *jtextfield* este me muestre los datos en un *jtable*, el problema es que no sé por qué me aparece el error:

> Operation not allowed for a result set of ResultSet. TYPE_FORWARD_ONLY

Creo el modelo de tabla:

```
//Crear un modelo de la tabla
DefaultTableModel modelo = new DefaultTableModel();

//asignar loss titulos de las columnas al modelo
modelo.setColumnIdentifiers(new Object[]{"Id Empleado",
    "Nombre", "Dirección", "Teléfono", "Celular",
    "Email", "Sexo"});
//variable para crear la conexion
Connection conn = null;

//Variable para manipular datos
PreparedStatement psSeleccionar = null;
ResultSet rs = null;
```

Realizo la conexión a la base de datos:

```
try {
           
    // Código para conexión:

    conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3307/controlfares","root", "");

    // **Consulta para seleccionar los datos de la tabla**

    String Consulta = "Select Id_Empleado,Nom_Empleado,"
                    + "Direccion,Tel_Empleado,Cel_Empleado,Email,Sexo "
                    + "from empleados where Nom_Empleado LIKE ('%" + jTFBuscarEmpleado.getText() + "%')";
    //Preparar la consulta de seleccionar a ejecutar
    psSeleccionar = conn.prepareStatement(Consulta);

    //Ejecutar la consulta y almacenar el resultado en rs
    rs = psSeleccionar.executeQuery(Consulta);
    
    // Creo que aquí parte el error    
        

    if (rs.next()) {
        rs.beforeFirst();
        while (rs.next()) {
            modelo.addRow(new Object[]{rs.getString("Id_Empleado"),
                    rs.getString("Nom_Empleado"), rs.getString("Direccion"),
                    rs.getString("Tel_Empleado"), rs.getString("Cel_Empleado"),
                    rs.getString("Email"), rs.getString("Sexo")});
        }
        jTEmpleados.setModel(modelo);
    } else {
        modelo.setRowCount(0);
        jTEmpleados.setModel(modelo);
    }
    conn.close();
} catch (SQLException ex) {
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, ex.getMessage(), "Conexion con DB Erronea", JOptionPane.WARNING_MESSAGE);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Cuando creas un resulset por defecto es solo de lectura hacia adelante, secuencial (TYPE_FORWARD_ONLY), por lo tanto, basta que quieras y hacia atras o ir hacia una posición determinada te da el error que solo es de lectura secuencial.

Para cambiar este comportamiento, se lo indicas al momento de crear el resultset. Adicionales a TYPE_FORWARD_ONLY, están:

*TYPE_SCROLL_INSENSITIVE*, el cuál te permite moverte por el el resultset hacia cualquier posición, sin embargo, cualquier actualización no se reflejaran en el resultset.

*TYPE_SCROLL_SENSITIIVE*, igual que el anterior con la diferencia que las actualizaciones se reflejan en el resultset.

Por lo anterior, deberías crear el resultset de esta forma:

```
psSeleccionar = conn.prepareStatement(Consulta,java.sql.ResultSet.TYPE_SCROLL_SENSITIIVE,java.sql.ResultSet.CONCUR_UPDATABLE);
```

En el tercer parametro se le indica si es de solo lectura (java.sql.ResultSet.CONCUR_READ_ONLY) o actualizable (java.sql.ResultSet.CONCUR_UPDATABLE).

Comment: increíble estimado! ese detalle era, muchas gracias!

Comment: ok, gusto en ayudarte y marca la respuesta como aceptada.